# Upgrading Couchdb 1.3 to 1.5 with Data?

Tags: couchdb, upgrade

Appreciate if anyone could guide me on how to upgrade couchdb 1.3 to 1.5? I've tried out upgrading the couchdb software and pointing the data directory to 1.3 versions' data directory location, which works fine so far. But is it the best and accurate way of doing it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Yup, that's the right way.

Here's quote from [CouchDB](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/COUCHDB/Current+Releases)

```
 CouchDB uses semantic versioning, so, in a nutshell:   
•X.Y.Z equates to major version, minor version, and patch version.  
•The major version will be incremented every time we make backwards incompatible changes.  
•The minor version will be incremented every time we add backwards compatible features.
•The patch version will be incremented every time we add backwards compatible fixes.
```